# Why devtools::document fails with unclear C++ error message?

Tags: r, build

I have a vignette that I can build using `devtools::build_vignettes()` but when I try to build the source package (RStudio/Build/build source package) it fails when executing `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))` with the following error message:

```
R(32119,0x7fff7437f000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff74dc0c30: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Exited with status 6.
```

This package uses `Rcpp` but I am definitely not an expert in Cpp and don't understand at all what is going on. I can use the package locally with no troubles.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.8    knitr_1.20        magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.4.0     devtools_2.0.1   
 [7] pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.3.0          rlang_0.3.0.1     tools_3.5.1       pkgbuild_1.0.2    sessioninfo_1.1.1
[13] cli_1.0.1         withr_2.1.2       htmltools_0.3.6   remotes_2.0.2     yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.0 
[19] digest_0.6.18     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.2.0    callr_3.0.0       clisymbols_1.2.0 
[25] base64enc_0.1-3   fs_1.2.6          ps_1.2.1          evaluate_0.12     glue_1.3.0        memoise_1.1.0    
[31] rmarkdown_1.10    compiler_3.5.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.2   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Comment: [mcve]? Does the error happen when you call `devtools::document()` directly with different `roclets`?

Comment: The error does not happen when I call the exacte same command from the Rstudio console

Comment: Also the command `devtools::build()` works from the RStudio console

Comment: Weird, but impossible to debug without a [mcve]. Make a copy of the project and remove stuff from it until you cannot remove anything without also removing this error message.

Comment: Removiing `Rcpp` tag ...

Comment: Have you tried to reboot? ;-)